# MapKit Coordinate Projection Gives Erroneous Results from Scene Renderer

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, scenekit

I am working on an app that overlays a MapKit Map View with a SceneKit SceneView (similar to https://blog.classycode.com/how-to-write-a-pok%C3%A9mon-go-clone-for-ios-edf1cf1cf5ce). In my scene I have a 3D node whose position is defined such that it appears on top of a specific map coordinate.

In the scene renderer I update the nodes position by converting the map coordinate to a point and projecting that point into the 3D scene. This method allows the user to rotate the map around while the 3D node appears to stay in place.

This is working. However, the node is "flickering" as the map changes. After investigating, I discovered that the culprit is the map coordinate conversion. For some reason, when the map is rotating, sometimes the converted screen coordinate is very wrong (somewhere off the screen).

I think the issue has something to do with threading. The map rotation angle is defined in the touchesMoved function and updated in the scene renderer. I have tried moving the map rotation and node position update to the touches moved function, but that made the converted points wrong every time.

Here is what my structure looks like:

```swift
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
     *grab map rotation angle start*
}

 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
     *calculate new map rotation angle*
}

extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

  func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
     *set map rotation angle*
     *update 3D node position*
}
```

I expect the map coordinate conversion to always give me a screen point that makes sense (I know the coordinate is on the screen), but the result is intermittently wrong during rotation.

UPDATE:

Two interesting new discoveries:

1) The problem only exists when map type = sateliteFlyover (unfortunately the one I need)

2) The problem goes away when using Apple's default user-interactive map rotation (also unfortunate because I need to control the rotation differently)

It really seems like some sort of thread processing issue where there is a "dead time" after the map camera has been changed that coordinate projection just gives the wrong value. But what could Apple be doing differently from me in their rotation method that eliminates this problem?